# Draw loop and Lua (Luabridge)

Tags: c++, loops, lua, draw, sfml

I'm currently stuck on some issue and don't know how to fix it.

I started working on a simple 2D engine using SFML for rendering stuff and Lua as my scripting language.
The engine starts with a splash screen first before Lua code is loaded ...

My problem is I don't know how to write a "good" draw loop for my Lua objects.
Maybe you'll understand when we take a look on my code:

Main.cpp:

```
...

int draw_stuff()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), TITLE);

    while (window.isOpen()) {

        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

    window.clear();

    if (!success) {
        window.draw(sp_splash_screen);
    }

    if (clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() > 2) {

        for (static bool first = true; first; first = false)
        {
            std::thread thr(&lua_module);
            thr.detach();

            success = true;
        }
    }


    for (sf::CircleShape obj : CircleDrawList) {
        window.draw(obj);
        //window.draw(CircleDrawList.front());
    }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

My CircleShape wrapper class for Lua:

```
/////shapes.h

extern std::list<sf::CircleShape> CircleDrawList;

class Circle
{
public:

    Circle();

         ...

    void draw();

private:
    sf::CircleShape circleShape;

protected:
    //~Circle();();
};


/////shapes.cpp

std::list<sf::CircleShape> CircleDrawList;

 ...

void Circle::draw()
{
    //std::cout << "DRAW IN LIST" << std::endl;

    CircleDrawList.push_front(circleShape);
    //if (drawableList.size() == 4)
        //drawableList.pop_front();
}

 ...

int luaopen_shapes(lua_State *L)
{
    luabridge::getGlobalNamespace(L)
        .beginClass<Circle>("Circle")
        .addConstructor <void(*) (void)>()

                 ... "other stuff to register" ...

        .addFunction("draw", &Circle::draw)
        .endClass();

    return 1;
}
```

and finally (if needed) my lua script:

```
local ball = Circle()
ball:setColor(255,0,0,255)

while true do

    ball:draw()

end
```

Result when the Lua Circle is moving by increasing one of the Vector2 values:

[image]

Hope you can help and I described it good :x

Thanks :)

-- Updated code in main.cpp

Comment: Because you never clear the window before drawing the ball?

Comment: sure I do ... the issue is related to the list thing ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is happening, but I see some problems in the code.

First: you don't remove "old" CircleShapes from `CircleDrawList`.

In the function `Circle::draw()` you are pushing object to the front of the list with `CircleDrawList.push_front(circleShape);` but you never remove anything from it. Using `CircleDrawList.front()` gives you access to the first element but you have to use method `pop_front()` to remove it.

Second thing. Look at the code:

```
//iterating through whole list with range-for:
for (sf::CircleShape obj : CircleDrawList)
{
    //why do you use CircleDrawList.front()?
    //You should probably use obj here!
    window.draw(CircleDrawList.front());
}
```

As for now this code draws first element of the list `n` times where `n` is the length of the CircleDrawList. Do you really want to do this?

Moreover you are drawing splash every frame. If you wish to display splash only at the beginning, then the line `window.draw(splash_screen); // splash screen before Lua script is loaded` should probably be in some sort of conditional instruction.

I don't know what is between drawing splash_screen and drawing circles. It could have some impact on what we see on the screen.

And one more thing: it is strongly recommended to avoid using global variables. `CircleDrawList` is a global variable and my advice would be to put it at least in some namespace, or even better to enclose it in some class.

Comment: I take it that `success` is defined and initalised properly somwhere before it's used ;) .
Did changing `window.draw(CircleDrawList.front());` to `window.draw(obj);` have any effect?

Comment: when I do `window.draw(CircleDrawList.front());` I have a single circle, but laggy window (cant click or drag it without crashing). When I use `window.draw(obj);` I have this line thing from my screenshot. btw. I wrote the lists into the object class :)

Comment: Then try to clear a list in function `Circle::draw`. As I understand from your code you are drawing only one object for now.
So, for testing purposes: before doing `push_front()` invoke `CircleDrawList.clear()` .
Because now you are adding new object to the list with every loop run: `while true do ball:draw() end` .

Comment: Did already tried that ... wait I a made a few screenshots of that. It crashed in all cases ... 

http://i.imgur.com/YEZIoML.png

http://i.imgur.com/5z6oADI.png

http://i.imgur.com/2Xh3iiZ.png

Comment: But you do it in the main while loop (if I see correctly on the screenshots). Try clearing the list in `Circle::draw` before doing `push_front`.

Comment: I tried that too. Result, flashing circle and then lag (until it freezes) :(

 `if (!CircleDrawList.empty())
 CircleDrawList.pop_front();

 CircleDrawList.push_front(circleShape);`

Comment: @Memorix101 Then I'm out of ideas for now. I have to think on it a bit :D .
Would it be possible for you to post me the code?

Comment: Sure, if you have bitbucket I can give you access to my private git :)